# sitecore link filed renderer to include atrribute from rte filed in anchor

Tags: renderfield

I have one rte filed with some value like `data-custom = '{test}'`.

I am using                                  `@Html.Sitecore().Field("LINK", Model.Item, new { @class = "testclass"})`.

How to add value from rte filed and append to anchor tag?

Comment: If the data attribute name is always the same, you could use approach shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158550/how-to-add-data-attributes-in-sitecore-mvc-fileds. Then move content of data-attribute to plain text field, add that to model and out put.

Comment: no data attribute name is not always same.

Comment: @kuldeep My suggestion is customization. You can achieve this by creating a custom HTML helper in your Sitecore solution. The custom HTML helper will extract the value from the RTE field, and then you can use it to construct the anchor tag.